# Refresh data from oracle database on jsf page refresh in adf 12c

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I am using jdeveloper 12c to build fusion web app with oracle 12c database.
My project is running fine in browser and also can be accessible on other system's browser via static IP.
When someone is accessing application in browser and enter some data in table, it saves in database but it doesn't reflects on my browser even after refreshing page until unless i rebuild my project.
How can i get data without rebuilding my project (I want to fetch all updated data through page refresh).
I don't want to create a method for this.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Only you need to add EXECUTE button from that specific table (of which you want to refresh data) operation in data control tab, and you can label it as REFRESH button.

Answer (score 0):

Browser page refresh doesn't call data querying. You need to call Execute on needed iterators. For instance you can start a taskflow with Execute method before showing user interface.

Comment: Another thing you could do is to set iterators' Refresh attribute to "always".

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but, use Execute of that particular VO after commiting the data.Before using Execute in java code you have to add Execute in page deinition or go to that particular table in page. use binding property under property inspector. create the binding as given  #{backingBeanScope.popupBean.refresh} and call it in java as like this to refresh the data while saving in DB 'AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(refresh);'